# cakephpでログイン済みユーザーの判定

Tags: php, cakephp

cake2.xでlogin処理を行いログイン済みのユーザがloginアクションに再びアクセスしようとしている時はログインユーザーのユーザー情報を取得しログインしていれば他のページにリダイレクトしたいのですが、うまくいきません。

ログインしているかの判定は調べるところ `$this->Auth->user()` に情報がはい行っているか `$this->auth->loggedIn` で判定する方法があったので `$this->Auth->user()` を使用しログイン情報を取得しリダイレクトする処理を書いたのですがログイン済みのユーザーがアクセスされてしまいます、何か原因がわかるかたご教授願いたいです。

```
public function login() {
    $login_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if ($login_id) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('ログイン中です'));
        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('ログインに成功しました'));
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('メールアドレスまたは、パスワードが違います'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: 意図を判断しかねる誤字がいくつかあるので、今一度文書を見直してみてください。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/282565